# Listening for zoom reset event in JFreeChart

Tags: java, zooming, listener, jfreechart, reset

How can I listen to JFreeChart's zoom reset event?

Comment: Have you tried overriding `restoreAutoBounds()`?

Comment: @trashgod: No, I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

I did it using this:

```
ChartPanel DCP=new ChartPanel(DailyChart){
    @Override
    public void restoreAutoBounds(){
        super.restoreAutoDomainBounds();
        super.restoreAutoRangeBounds();

        XYPlot plot=(XYPlot)getChart().getPlot();

        Calendar Cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        String dayName=Cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SHORT,new Locale("en", "us")).toLowerCase();
        String tmp[]=((String)Configurations.getWeeklyWorkingSchedule().get(dayName).get("start")).split(":");
        Cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]));
        Cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]));
        Cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        long start=Cal.getTimeInMillis();
        tmp=((String)Configurations.getWeeklyWorkingSchedule().get(dayName).get("end")).split(":");
        Cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]));
        Cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]));
        Cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        long end=Cal.getTimeInMillis();

        plot.getDomainAxis().setAutoRange(false);
        plot.getDomainAxis().setRange(start,end);
    }
};
DCP.restoreAutoBounds();
```

Thank You all.

Comment: Thanks ... @trashgod :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add up on @trashgod suggestion, in case you want to *disable* zoom reset on a specific axis: create an overriden `ChartPanel` where you either "null" `restoreAutoDomainBounds()` or `restoreAutoRangeBounds()`, as shown below.

That can be useful when you control the viewing area from different components than the chart itself (in my case: the X axis is set by the program but the user can freely zoom in/out the Y axis).

```
ChartPanel cp = new ChartPanel(null) {
    @Override public void restoreAutoDomainBounds() {
        // Empty body: do not reset X zoom
    }
};
```