# How to set jfreechart auto range to the chosen values?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I draw a two-dimensional graph in which I set ranges for both axes by certain values. But when I select the graph menu 'auto range > both axes' I get other ranges (maybe obviously).

I want to set auto range into my defined range, with my values. How can I do this?

```
XYPlot xyPlot = chart.getXYPlot();
NumberAxis domainAxis = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getDomainAxis();

domainAxis.setRange(minXChart, maxXChart);
domainAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(xTickInterval));

rangeAxis.setRange(minYChart, maxYChart);
rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(yTickInterval));
```

1. [graph with defined range](https://s10.postimg.io/fzqi721u1/image.png) (i want exactly the same but with auto range)
2. [graph with auto range](https://s11.postimg.io/it6jj3htf/image.png) (bad looking)

Answer (score 1):

Some possible approaches:

- Override the `ChartPanel` method `restoreAutoBounds()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8712648/230513), to establish your preferred bounds.
- Remove the feature from the context menu using the `zoom` parameter of a suitable `ChartPanel` constructor and handle the action with your own control, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513) for <kbd>Auto Zoom</kbd>.

Comment: I've found solution only to part of my question associated with wrong autorange:

    '// fixing x axis
    NumberAxis domainAxis = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getDomainAxis();
    domainAxis.setLowerMargin(0);
    domainAxis.setUpperMargin(0);
    
    // fixing y axis
    NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getRangeAxis();
    rangeAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);'

Problem with lower border y axis was that all my data points are positive values.

But still I don't know how to set autorange to the chosen values.

Comment: Code in comments is incomplete and hard to read; please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.